# What happens when you cast the Fear spell on an Elemental?

Tags: firetop-mountain

What happens when you cast the Fear spell on an Elemental (Ice or Fire)? Is this possible that it doesn't hurt you on that turn? Or an elemental does know feat at all?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [spell guide](http://www.gamerz.net/~fm/Main/Spells.html) explicitly say that elementals are not affected by fear, so they should attack you as usual:

> If the subject of the spell is a monster (excluding elementals, which are unaffected), it will be too afraid to attack in that round.